# How to convert a Char pointer into a string?

Tags: c

How do I convert `char` pointer into a string?

I know it's a pointer to a string, but I don't want a pointer.

For example:

```
char* token;
char strings[50];
```

`char strings[50]` is a `char` string.

What is easiest way to turn `*token` into a string?

mbtowc turns `*token` in a single `char`, I don't want single `char`. Entire String.

Comment: Assuming `token` points to valid string data, use strcpy to copy into the array: `strcpy(strings, token)`

Comment: okay ill try that

Comment: The `strings` array is indistinguishable from an actual pointer in many cases. But not in all. So you may be able to use `token` directly. Please provide more info on what you are really trying to do.

Comment: `char strings[50]` is misleading because it's not multiple strings and it's not even a string, it's a char array. I think some terminology adjustment is necessary in order to determine what you need. Strings in C are null-terminated arrays of `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sad fact is that most C string library functions like `strcpy()`, `strncpy()` and `memcpy()` are somewhat lacking in terms of safely, reliably, and/or simply copying a C string into a char array.

Here's one way to do it:

```
size_t len = strlen(token);
if (len < sizeof(strings)) {
    memcpy(strings, token, len); // assumes token doesn't point inside strings, else use memmove()
    strings[len] = '\0';
} else {
    // input string was too long, handle the error somehow
}
```

As you can imagine, many projects implemented in C will define a few functions to handle C strings efficiently in whatever way they need, with appropriate error handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*until C99*/
char *token = "test";
char strings[50];
/* copy to sized buffer: */
strncpy ( strings, token, sizeof(strings) );
strings[sizeof(strings) - 1] = 0;

/*since C11*/
char *token = "test";
char strings[50];
/* returns zero on success, returns non-zero on error.*/
int r1 = strncpy_s(strings, sizeof(strings), token, strlen(token));
/*use strlen_s if not sure whether token is not null poiter*/
```

Comment: `strncpy()` is not safe at all, in that it does not guarantee null termination.  This leads to dangerous bugs.

Comment: @John Zwinck  strings[sizeof(strings) - 1] = 0; or you prefere strncpy_s ?